# IBM WAS autoreconnect to IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-8

I have a Java EE aplication on IBM WAS 8.5.5.x which connects to IBM MQ 9.0 with Activation specs.
I'm interested in problem of autoreconnecting from WAS to MQ, if for some reason there was a connection loss (MQ server was shut down).

In IBM WAS admin console I have set Resources -> JMS -> Queue connection factories -> Factory -> Advanced properties -> Client reconnect options -> RECONNECT

I set Client reconnect timeout to 120 seconds.

That worked well (there was a reconnection) until queue manager was ended for a long period of time (about 9 hours).

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there a way to make QCF or Activation Spec auto reconnect if there was a connection loss. Is there a limit on number of reconnetion tries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior can be controlled by updating the "***Reconnection retry count***" and "***Reconnection retry interval***" properties for "WebSphere MQ messaging provider" JMS provider in WAS console.

Path :Resources > JMS Providers > WebSphere MQ messaging provider (select scope) > Resource adapter properties (under Additional properties) .

> **Reconnection retry count** : The maximum number of attempts made by a WebSphere MQ messaging provider activation specification to reconnect to a WebSphere MQ queue manager if a connection fails.
>   **Reconnection retry interval** : The time, in milliseconds, that a WebSphere MQ messaging provider activation specification waits before making another attempt to reconnect to a WebSphere MQ queue manager.

Refer : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/umj_pjmswmq_raprops.html for more details.

Comment: We both posted an answer at the same time.  I think that my answer while addressing a setting the OP tried is things that do not fall under "activation specification".  Do you know if the setting I provided documentation on interacts with the setting you provided?  It think in the case of activation spec my answer is incorrect, let me know what you think.

Comment: From what i understand, Activation specs are independent of QCF configurations, and hence the QCF "Client reconnect timeout" won't have any impact on the reconnect behavior of Activation specs.

Comment: And FYI, in case of QCF's, "Client reconnect options" is "DISABLED" by default and hence any changes to "Client reconnect timeout" will not take effect, unless the "Client reconnect options" is also updated.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I'll delete my answer for now unless the OP wants the info on QCF.